# C# Selenium, получить наименьший объект из строки Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

подскажите, пожалуйста [image: Имеется диапазон от 0.4 - 0.5]

В поле кол-во факт требуется выставить минимальное значение из диапазона (т.е 0.4), подскажите каким способом это будет лучше сделать, есть что то универсальное или только расчеты.
Какой лучшее применение будет в этом случае (распарсить строку, Xpath, расчеты (хард)).

Comment: А у вас есть выбор? Вам как не крути надо узнать этот диапазон, он есть только на сайте, а значит вам надо от туда его сначала взять и распарсить.  Вообще, я вангую, что селениум вам вовсе не нужен, достаточно простых POST/GET запросов.

Comment: Без селениум никак, проект по автотестам, пишу сценарий на определенный стек

Comment: Ну "никак" - я бы поспорил, а так, если вы используете его по назначению, то без проблем. Многие просто пишут "ботов" для сайтов на селениуме, думая это единым вариантом и не понимая, что селениум - инструмент тестирования, но не автоматизации.